# How can I 'lift' certain attributes from a wrapped value to the wrapper?

Tags: python, wrapper

I have a class that wraps an instance of another class:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

class WrapperList(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

class Value(object):
    is_square = True

class OtherValue(object):
    is_round = True

w = Wrapper(TheValue())
wl = WrapperList([TheValue(), OtherValue()])
```

And I've got some other code that consumes the Wrapper, but needs to inspect the properties on the wrapped value. The consumer doesn't know the value is wrapped though.

```
def process(value):
    if value.is_square:
        do_something(value)
process(w)
```

But a different implementation doesn't care if the value is a square, it only cares if it is round:

```
def process(value):
    if value.is_round:
        do_something(value)
process(w2)
```

What I had been doing, was this:

```
class WrapperList(object):
    is_square = False
    is_round = False
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped
        self.is_square = any(w.is_square for w in wrapped if hasattr(w, 'is_square'))
        self.is_round = any(w.is_round for w in wrapped if hasattr(w, 'is_round'))
```

But that's non-ideal for a number of reasons. For one, a different implementation might want to know if something `is_triangle`. Now the Wrapper needs to know about that attribute also. Further, users may define their own Value types and their own implementation that deals with wrapped values.

There are two ways I have thought of for dealing with this, but I'm not partial to either, and would appreciate any input. The first is by using `__getattr__`:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if hasattr(self.wrapped, name):
            return getattr(self.wrapped, name)
        else:
            raise AttributeError
```

This seems ok, but becomes a little more difficult when we're talking about a Wrapper that wraps a list of value types.

The second option is a little more creative, but feels like a giant hack to me, as it requires the value to know that it is being wrapped (which isn't a massive problem, it just smells):

```
class Value(object):
    is_square = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.promoted_attributes = {'is_square': True}

class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        for attr, val in wrapped.promoted_attributes.items():
            setattr(self, attr, val)
```

This second method has the benefit of being able to be very explicit about which values should be promoted to the wrapper, but doesn't feel right at all.

Is there a better way of handling this situation? I'm working with both python 2.7 and 3.3+.

Comment: What would attribute access on the `WrapperList` look like? The `__getattr__` method is the way to go, really; just return `getattr(self.wrapped, name)` and let that raise the `AttributeError`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the WrapperList would need to check all of the children and return the greatest value. If 3 of the values had a False value, but 1 had a True value, then the True value should be promoted. There are other non-bool values that *could* be promoted, but they aren't necessary. At the moment, only the bool class attributes are necessary.

Comment: Then code that functionality in the `__getattr__` method of the `WrapperList` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find several aspects of your design questionable. One is that it seems like `Wrapper` is just a special case of a `WrapperList` with one wrapped value. The following corrects this and "lifts" the attributes of any wrapped objects in a generic way. If you only wanted to lift certain attributes, it could be modified to handle that, too, without a lot of difficulty.

```
class AutoWrapper(object):
    wrapped = ()
    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        for obj in self.wrapped:
            try:
                return getattr(obj, attrname)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        raise AttributeError(attrname)

class Thing(AutoWrapper):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.wrapped = args

class TheValue(object):
    is_square = True

class OtherValue(object):
    is_round = True

def do_something(obj):
    print('do_something to {}'.format(obj))

def process(value):
    if value.is_square:
        do_something(value)

thing1 = Thing(TheValue(), OtherValue())

process(thing1)  # -> do_something to <__main__.Thing object at 0x020E5350>
```

Answer (score 1):

define `__getattr__` in `WrapperList`:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    return any(getattr(w, attr, False) for w in self.wrapped)
```